# How to deconstruct an array and put it into the "main" array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I deconstruct an array, and put it into the array which it is getting mapped on, and then continue sorting on that?

The array looks like the following after filtering it:

```
[
    ['traitName', 'value'],
    ['traitName', ['value01', 'value02', 'value03' ...] ],
    //...
]
```

I want to check every trait, and check if the first index is an array, then deconstruct that, and put it into this array like this:

```
[
    ['traitName', 'value'],
    ['traitName', value01],
    ['traitName', value02],
    ['traitName', value03],
    //...
],
```

Then I can continue sorting on this array.

```
Object.entries(nft)
    .filter((val: any) => val[0] !== 'Attributes' && data.attributes[val[0]] !== undefined)
    .sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (typeof a[1] === 'number') return Infinity;
      return (
        data.attributes[a[0]]?.values[a[1]]?.distribution - data.attributes[b[0]]?.values[b[1]]?.distribution
      );
    })
```

I need to this between the filter and sorting I think.

Comment: Your `sort` callback refers to `attributes` and `values` and `distribution`, ... What is that about?

Comment: I think that shouldn't matter for this question, thats just how its getting sorted, but its equal to data.attributes[traitName].values[value].distribution which is a percentage number.

Comment: Can you remove the things from your question that are unrelated to it? Instead of speaking of the filtering and sorting, it would be better to focus on realistic data (without `...` and without syntax issues)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to do this:

```js
const data = [
  ['traitName', 'value'],
  ['traitName', ['value01', 'value02', 'value03']],
]

const output = data.flatMap(
  ([n, v]) => (Array.isArray(v) ? v : [v]).map(vv => [n, vv])
);

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this,

```
const a = [
    ['traitName', 'value'],
    ['traitName', ['value01', 'value02', 'value03'] ]
    
]

let final = []
a.forEach((item)=>{
    console.log(typeof item[1])
    if(typeof item[1] == "string") {
        final.push(item)
    } else if(typeof item[1] == 'object') {
        let len = item[1].length
        item[1].forEach((item2) =>{
            let e = [item[0], item2]
            final.push(e)
        })
    }
})
console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be achieved by using `.map`, `.concat` and `.flat()`, in one line as shown below:

```
arr.map(([x, y]) => ([].concat(y).map(z => ([x, z])))).flat()
```

One possible solution is shown below:

**Code Snippet**

```js
const arr = [
    ['traitName', 'value'],
    ['traitName', ['value01', 'value02', 'value03'] ]
];

const res = arr.map(
  ar => (
      [].concat(ar[1])
      .map(x => ([ar[0], x]))
    )
)
.flat();

console.log('result using .map & .flat: ', res);

// or in just one line:
console.log(
  'one line result: ',
  arr.map(([x, y]) => ([].concat(y).map(z => ([x, z])))).flat()
);
```

**Explanation**

- Iterate over the original array
- Use `[].concat()` to treat the second element of each inner-array as an array
- Use `.map()` to iterate over the inner-array element/s
- Return the desired result
- Use `.flat()` to flatten the resulting array.